# dumping vcd files in Modelsim simulations

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim, edaplayground

I am trying to dump a vcd file when simulating with modelsim, however, I don't get anything in my "dumpVCD.vcd" file. The syntax I am usingin .do file is as follows:

```
vcd file dumpVCD.vcd
vcd add -r /dff_TB/*
```

however the `dumpVCD.vcd` file doesn't have the waveforms.

I have uploaded the test on edaplayground ([link](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2aTT)).

I would appreciate it if someone could advise me what is the problem with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a runtime optimization switch `-voptargs=+acc=npr` to preserve signal visibility. I'll put in a request to have this on by default.